# Influencing automatic type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say that I'm writing a function that returns some sort of proxy object, let's say for lazy evaluation or some other purpose. If I write code like

```
auto x = func();
```

then `x` will be the type of the return value - *not* the type of the object that I wanted proxied. Is it possible to alter `auto` or `decltype` so that using them in this situation will return the actual result that I want returned, rather than the type of the proxy object itself?

Comment: Not that I know of. I saw at least two suggestions for "operator auto()" conversion operators that are intended to trigger a conversion in this case. But nobody wrote a serious proposal for that.

Comment: I fail to see where you would need this. Either you want the real proxy type (like some expression template, and then you'd be glad to use `auto`), or the result of a conversion. In the latter case, you can spell out the type (or `typedef` it), like we used to do in C++03. Do you have a particular example in mind where such a feature would provide a clear advantage ?

Answer (score 3):

Random thoughts:

You could possibly get at the type of the proxied object by using `decltype(*func())`, or however the proxied object is accessed. There are no modifiers to `auto` other than the usual `const`, `&`, etc.

If it is a lazy evaluation, you probably don't want the final object type right now, do you?

If the proxy has a cenversion operator to the final object, how could `auto` know that it should be used? What if there are more than one?

Answer (score 0):

Why not type cast it inside `func()` to what you want when returning?